# How to debug source IP which try to access SSH server through port forwarding by SSH

Tags: ssh, security, sshd, port, forwarding

my case is likely following case: SSH client(192.168.0.11) -> public cloud VM with SSH server and setup port forwarding (139.90.90.90)(CentOS7.9)-> one internal SSH server(10.24.24.24)(CentOS 7.9).
I have created port forwarding to access one of my internal SSH server and I can access it through a public cloud VM with specific port.

```
ssh -L *:10100:10.24.24.24:10100 -N -f aa@139.90.90.90
```

My laptop SSH client can access 139.90.90.90:10100 successfully.

But recently, I found one issue: since I open port on Internet, there have many invalid SSH login requests which sometimes make the server cost additional resources. It should be not safe, so I use `firewalld-cmd` to reject some source IP.

My question is about how to detect those source IPs? Since at internal SSH server, it will just show public cloud IP address which 139.90.90.90. For example, like following on my internal Linux Server (`/var/log/secure`):

> ```
> May 10 23:48:46 z1 sshd[17066]: input_userauth_request: invalid user nano [preauth]
> May 10 23:48:46 z1 sshd[17066]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
> May 10 23:48:46 z1 sshd[17066]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=139.90.90.90
> May 10 23:48:48 z1 sshd[17066]: Failed password for invalid user nano from 139.90.90.90 port 40800 ssh2
> ```

Any idea how can I find out the source IP then I may block that in my public cloud server through firewalld.

Thanks,
Eugene

Comment: "_my laptop SSH client can access 139.90.90.90:10100 successfully_" That doesn't make sense in the context of the information you've given us. Assuming the ssh  command succeeds, your laptop can ssh to the standard port 22 on the remote host 139.90.90.90. This connection also attempts to allow anyone with access to your laptop port 10100 to connect to a service running on port 10100 on the host 10.24.24.24 that is reachable via your host 139.90.90.90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I didn't find a way to identify it accurately. But I found one possible to help block those attackers (hackers). Change the SSH config file with " LogLevel DEBUG1", then you should see many entries like "server_request_direct_tcpip: originator 128.199.32.98 port 48498, target 211.95.84.14 ", at that point, you can check if those IPs are valid. 
Then you can make a script to check if invalid IP, and block the connection.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family=ipv4 source address=$IP reject"
```

You can also make a white list to allow valid connections.